# why copying take too long from my server to External drive

Tags: file-transfer, copying

I don't understand why copying 244 GB of data from a Window server would be copying at the rate of 10.49KB/sec. The server RAM is 48 GB, Processor 2.19GHZ and hard drive of 1.75TB out which 491GB is free. I am copying sqlserver backup files using Super Copier. What could be the problem or cause of this. I am copying this file locally not over a network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10.49 KB/sec is the buffer write speed, not the physical write speed. So depending of your setting (number of thread per copy and buffer size) the real copy could be slower (very slower) than that.

Also, older version of supercopier have some file size limitation (I never could copy a file of at leasst 60 Gb file on an ealier 32bit version).

Try with a robotcopy to see if the limitation is still the same (and verify that your anti-virus is not blocking the file)